# Is it correct to say "My bunny's ears are weird. One stands up and the other hangs down at once"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

If a bunny is happy, its ears stand up, and if it is not happy, its ears hang down.

Is it correct to say:

-"**My bunny's ears are weird. One stands up and the other hangs down at once**"

-"**My bunny's ears are weird. One is up and the other is droopy**"

You can see the picture below

[image: rabbit with one ear up and the other down]

Comment: Can you clarify your question. The two examples you provide differ in several ways, so it's not clear if you are asking about: "stands up" vs "is up"; "hangs down" vs "is droopy"; or the use vs omission of "at once".

Comment: @tkp, I have just updated my question. I am wondering if  "**the ear stands up / hangs down**" or "**the ear is up/ droopy**" is a correct expression?

Comment: Some breeds of domestic rabbit have permanently [lop ears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lop_rabbit)

Comment: You have everything that you need in your first sentence.  Drop the *at once.*  It is not needed. *My bunny's ears are weird. One stands up and the other hangs down (or **droops)**.*  That is how I would say it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first option, I guess you are using "at once" to mean "at the same time"? Unfortunately, that's not how it would be read. So I'd simply remove it, since it's not really needed in this context. If you really wanted to stress the fact that the ears are doing their respective things at the same time, then you could change the "and" to "while".

But while your second option doesn't have that problem, I think it's inferior to the first because it contrasts "up" with "droopy", which isn't as clear as the first's contrast of "up" with "down".